# Puzzle Game Android DFS algorithm

Tags: java, android, algorithm, depth-first-search

I have a android application called Islands and bridges also known as [Hashiwokakero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashiwokakero)

The application uses A 2 Dimensional array that spawns the Islands randomly everytime the user restarts the game It form a Matrix with number from 0 to 4 where 0=null and 1-4 = Island There can be 2 bridges comming out of one Island to connect the other ,  The map at the moment is not solvable. To solve the game the user needs to connect the islands using bridges so if an island = 4 it needs 4 connection to it if an island = 2 it needs 2 connection and so on..

in my research i found out that the best algorithm to solve the game is to use Depth first search - [article](http://liacs.leidenuniv.nl/assets/Bachelorscripties/2009-11TimoMorsink.pdf)

I have looked at different question on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31616317/depth-first-search-on-2-d-array) but can't seem to find a solution as my array is of type `String` rather than `integer`.

**QUESTION** how can apply a DFS algorithm to connect the islands?

here is a screenshot of my application.

[image]

This the function to create a easy map 4x4 matrix:

```
private void InitializeEasy() {
      Random rand = new Random();
      String[][] debug_board_state = new String[4][4];
      setCurrentState(new State(WIDTH_EASY));
      for (int row = 0; row < debug_board_state.length; row++) {
          for (int column = 0; column < debug_board_state[row].length; column++) {
              debug_board_state[row][column] = String.valueOf(rand.nextInt(5));

          }
      }

      for (int row = 0; row < debug_board_state.length; row++) {
          for (int column = 0; column < debug_board_state[row].length; column++) {
              System.out.print(debug_board_state[row][column] + " ");
          }
          System.out.println();
      }
      for (int row = 0; row < WIDTH_EASY; ++row) {
          for (int column = 0; column < WIDTH_EASY; ++column) {
              for (int colNum = column - 1; colNum <= (column + 1); colNum += 1) {

                  getCurrentState().board_elements[row][column] = new BoardElement();
                  getCurrentState().board_elements[row][column].max_connecting_bridges = Integer.parseInt(debug_board_state[row][column]);
                  getCurrentState().board_elements[row][column].row = row;
                  getCurrentState().board_elements[row][column].col = column;

                  if (getCurrentState().board_elements[row][column].max_connecting_bridges > 0) {
                      getCurrentState().board_elements[row][column].is_island = true;
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to start building the board one island at a time using valid moves so that a solvable solution exists? May want to look through: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: So,just to make sure you are saying that i should build one island at a time checking the connection then build next one do the same and so on?

Comment: Correct. Right now if I understand your game rules correctly the size 4 islands at the edges make the board unwinnable as it can at most have 3 connections.

Comment: Yes thats correct, I could use a hardcoded array to make this work but my goal is to spawn the map at random.

Comment: If you want to add 'dead ends' to get a interesting board, add those at the end after you have created solvable board. Good luck.

Comment: @MorrisonChang I forgot to mention that there can be two bridges going out from one island

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DFS could be applied to the game state.

Pseudo algorithm:

1. pick a random (or by some other criterium) island that still needs bridges
2. build a bridge between this island and one of its neighbors (obviously a neighbor that also needs a bridge)
3. push the new state of the game (for instance the connectivity matrix of this graph) on a stack
4. if the game contains inconsistencies, pop 1 item from the stack
5. go back to step 1, using the top of the stack as the current state

As I mentioned, this is a piece of pseudo-code.
You will need to refine it to handle edge-cases.
You should also think about strategies to prevent the branching factor from becoming too large.

example (not thoroughly tested, not thoroughly debugged):

```
int[][] STARTING_CLUES = {
        {2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 3},
        {0, 1, 4, 0, 4, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {3, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2},
        {2, 0, 4, 0, 2, 0}
};

void search(){

    Map<Point, List<Direction>> remainingOptions = new HashMap<>();

    Stack<Land> gameTree = new Stack<>();
    gameTree.push(new Land(STARTING_CLUES));

    while(true){

        Land state = gameTree.peek();
        int[] p = state.lowestTodo();
        if (p == null)
            System.out.println("solution found");

        // move to next game state
        int r = p[0];
        int c = p[1];
        System.out.println("expanding game state for node at (" + r + ", " + c + ")");

        List<Direction> ds = null;
        if(remainingOptions.containsKey(new Point(r,c)))
            ds = remainingOptions.get(new Point(r,c));
        else{
            ds = new ArrayList<>();
            for(Direction dir : Direction.values()) {
                int[] tmp = state.nextIsland(r, c, dir);
                if(tmp == null)
                    continue;
                if(state.canBuildBridge(r,c,tmp[0], tmp[1]))
                    ds.add(dir);
            }
            remainingOptions.put(new Point(r,c), ds);
        }

        // if the node can no longer be expanded, and backtracking is not possible we quit
        if(ds.isEmpty() && gameTree.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("no valid configuration found");
            return;
        }

        // if the node can no longer be expanded, we need to backtrack
        if(ds.isEmpty()){
            gameTree.pop();
            remainingOptions.remove(new Point(r,c));
            System.out.println("going back to previous decision");
            continue;
        }

        Direction dir = ds.remove(0);
        System.out.println("connecting " + dir.name());
        remainingOptions.put(new Point(r,c), ds);

        Land nextState = new Land(state);
        int[] tmp = state.nextIsland(r,c,dir);
        nextState.connect(r,c, tmp[0], tmp[1]);
        gameTree.push(nextState);

    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main().search();
}
```

I also wrote a utility class that handles the common operations on the piece of land on which bridges need to be built (like finding the next available island, checking whether a bridge can be built, etc)

```
public class Land {

private int[][] BRIDGES_TO_BUILD;

private boolean[][] IS_ISLAND;
private Direction[][] BRIDGES_ALREADY_BUILT;

public Land(int[][] bridgesToDo){
    BRIDGES_TO_BUILD = copy(bridgesToDo);

    int R = bridgesToDo.length;
    int C = bridgesToDo[0].length;
    BRIDGES_ALREADY_BUILT = new Direction[R][C];
    IS_ISLAND = new boolean[R][C];
    for(int i=0;i<R;i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < C; j++) {
            BRIDGES_ALREADY_BUILT[i][j] = null;
            IS_ISLAND[i][j] = bridgesToDo[i][j] > 0;
        }
    }
}

public Land(Land other){
    BRIDGES_TO_BUILD = copy(other.BRIDGES_TO_BUILD);
    int R = BRIDGES_TO_BUILD.length;
    int C = BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[0].length;
    BRIDGES_ALREADY_BUILT = new Direction[R][C];
    IS_ISLAND = new boolean[R][C];
    for(int i=0;i<R;i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < C; j++) {
            BRIDGES_ALREADY_BUILT[i][j] = other.BRIDGES_ALREADY_BUILT[i][j];
            IS_ISLAND[i][j] = other.IS_ISLAND[i][j];
        }
    }
}

public int[] next(int r, int c, Direction dir){
    int R = BRIDGES_TO_BUILD.length;
    int C = BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[0].length;

    // out of bounds
    if(r < 0 || r >=R || c < 0 || c >= C)
        return null;


    // motion vectors
    int[][] motionVector = {{-1, 0},{0,1},{1,0},{0,-1}};
    int i = Arrays.asList(Direction.values()).indexOf(dir);

    // calculate next
    int[] out = new int[]{r + motionVector[i][0], c + motionVector[i][1]};

    r = out[0];
    c = out[1];

    // out of bounds
    if(r < 0 || r >=R || c < 0 || c >= C)
        return null;

    // return
    return out;
}

public int[] nextIsland(int r, int c, Direction dir){
    int[] tmp = next(r,c,dir);
    if(tmp == null)
        return null;
    while(!IS_ISLAND[tmp[0]][tmp[1]]){
        tmp = next(tmp[0], tmp[1], dir);
        if(tmp == null)
            return null;
    }
    return tmp;
}

public boolean canBuildBridge(int r0, int c0, int r1, int c1){
    if(r0 == r1 && c0 > c1){
        return canBuildBridge(r0, c1, r1, c0);
    }
    if(c0 == c1 && r0 > r1){
        return canBuildBridge(r1, c0, r0, c1);
    }
    if(r0 == r1){
        int[] tmp = nextIsland(r0, c0, Direction.EAST);
        if(tmp[0] != r1 || tmp[1] != c1)
            return false;
        if(BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[r0][c0] == 0)
            return false;
        if(BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[r1][c1] == 0)
            return false;
        for (int i = c0; i <= c1 ; i++) {
            if(IS_ISLAND[r0][i])
                continue;
            if(BRIDGES_ALREADY_BUILT[r0][i] == Direction.NORTH)
                return false;
        }
    }
    if(c0 == c1){
        int[] tmp = nextIsland(r0, c0, Direction.SOUTH);
        if(tmp[0] != r1 || tmp[1] != c1)
            return false;
        if(BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[r0][c0] == 0 || BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[r1][c1] == 0)
            return false;
        for (int i = r0; i <= r1 ; i++) {
            if(IS_ISLAND[i][c0])
                continue;
            if(BRIDGES_ALREADY_BUILT[i][c0] == Direction.EAST)
                return false;
        }
    }
    // default
    return true;
}

public int[] lowestTodo(){
    int R = BRIDGES_TO_BUILD.length;
    int C = BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[0].length;

    int[] out = {0, 0};
    for (int i=0;i<R;i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < C; j++) {
            if(BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[i][j] == 0)
                continue;
            if (BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[out[0]][out[1]] == 0)
                out = new int[]{i, j};
            if (BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[i][j] < BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[out[0]][out[1]])
                out = new int[]{i, j};
        }
    }
    if (BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[out[0]][out[1]] == 0) {
        return null;
    }
    return out;
}

private int[][] copy(int[][] other){
    int[][] out = new int[other.length][other.length == 0 ? 0 : other[0].length];
    for(int r=0;r<other.length;r++)
        out[r] = Arrays.copyOf(other[r], other[r].length);
    return out;
}

public void connect(int r0, int c0, int r1, int c1){
    if(r0 == r1 && c0 > c1){
        connect(r0, c1, r1, c0);
        return;
    }
    if(c0 == c1 && r0 > r1){
        connect(r1, c0, r0, c1);
        return;
    }
    if(!canBuildBridge(r0, c0, r1, c1))
        return;

    BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[r0][c0]--;
    BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[r1][c1]--;

    if(r0 == r1){
        for (int i = c0; i <= c1 ; i++) {
            if(IS_ISLAND[r0][i])
                continue;
            BRIDGES_ALREADY_BUILT[r0][i] = Direction.EAST;
        }
    }
    if(c0 == c1){
        for (int i = r0; i <= r1 ; i++) {
            if(IS_ISLAND[i][c0])
                continue;
            BRIDGES_ALREADY_BUILT[i][c0] = Direction.NORTH;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: great answer could you maybe provide a code example?

Comment: is `Direction` part of the `Path.Direction` or is it a sample class?

Comment: It's an enum of the 4 directions (north, east, south, west).

Comment: I am running the code, I generate the first row of the matrix, and the the program crashes, I am left with `Attempt to read from null array` error any idea?

Comment: I would suggest you create a new question, with your entire runnable code, and then ask for help. In general, it is frowned upon to simply ask people to solve your problem for you at StackOverflow.

Comment: This line here crashes the algorithm for me `if(tmp[0] != r1 || tmp[1] != c1)
            return false;` i tried to debug it i get the following values`tmp: null` `r1: 0` and `c1: 1`